# vicious circle between "sudo dpkg--reconfigure -a" and "kernel panic"

Tags: kernel

I am using Ubuntu 13.04, today I run software manager, it listed lots of stuff around 250mb including new kernel 3.8.0-32 and while installing them kernel panic occured, I shut down my laptop on power button. Then I restarted it, it successfully loaded session but when I open synaptic I get:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

when I run it kernel panic occur again, it happens while it's configuring "libc" or something like that. Please help!!!

**Edit:**

`uname -r` gives me still `3.8.0-31` version of the kernel.

**Edit2:**

It's obviously a `libc` configuration problem, so now how can I revert it back to previous version? Related packages in cache:

```
libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb, libc6-dev_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb, libc-dev-bin_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb, linux-libc-dev_3.8.0-32.47_i386.deb
```

Is it possible to downgrade them while getting `sudo dpkg --configure -a` error?

**Edit3:**

I run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic
```

It could configure the previous kernel, so it's not kernel upgrade issue.

Comment: Mean of "kernel panic" to you? I don't understand that.
Can you copy the text in the terminal or give me the screenshot?

Comment: kernel panic happens when I run  'sudo dpkg --configure -a', I check out process in terminal when it tries to configure libc stuff kernel panic arises.

Comment: I think you should provided a screenshot of the terminal because it is not clear.

Comment: It's impossible from inside of computer because it immediately switches to text mode.

Comment: Have you tried recovery mode?

Comment: Why? It opens desktop without problem but when I attempt to install a program it keep asking to  run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'"

Comment: Yes, run that command in recovery mode. I don't sure but you should try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG! I fixed it at last. I downloaded above packages from [ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386/libc6/download)

and then installed them one by one with "sudo dpkg -i *.deb" and all of them installed successfully.
Phew!

Comment: Please fix your link, it was not found.

Comment: Actually I found them like `site:http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386  libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb` in google

Comment: Your google search term returned a empty list.

Comment: sorry I did typos in a hurry `site:packages.ubuntu.com libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5_i386.deb` I remember I deleted ".1" in version numbers because previous version numbers contain "-0ubuntu5_" not"-0ubuntu5.1_" but you must install the ones which contain "-0ubuntu5.1_"